# How to fix 'sh: 1: path/to/file not found ' python random generator

Tags: python

Hey all having a little issue with my code. I am creating a random food picker for my girlfriend whenever she tells me that she doesn't know where to eat

I am using aiys voice kit on a raspberry pi zero w and cloud text to speech API so the command process is like this

--- User Presses button

"Cloud speech is listening"

User Says "Where should we go for food"

run rndfoodpkr() ---

I also tried using omxplayer instead of mixer

```py
def rndfoodpkr():
    randomfile= random.choice(os.listdir(/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food/"))
    file = '/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food' + randomfile + '/'
    os.system ('mixer' + file)
```

rndfoodpkr() is supposed to run and select a random file inside the Food folder then mixer/omxplayer is supposed to run and play the .mp3 file however it gives this error

"sh: 1: mixer/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food/Wendys.mp3/: not found"

Same results for any file ie. Tacobell, McDonalds, arbys, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself that works great

```py
def rndfoodpkr ():
    path = "/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food"
    randomfile = os.path.join(path, random.choice(os.listdir(path)))
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(randomfile)
    mixer.music.play()
```

Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
file = '/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food' + randomfile
os.system ('mixer ' + file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems with this code:

1. There is a quotation mark missing before `/home` on the second line. I suspect you introduced this error when posting your question, as your program would not be running at all if this error were present.
2. You are inserting a slash in the wrong place when you generate `file` -- the path you end up generating would look like

   ```
   /home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/FoodFilename.mp3/
                                         ^^           ^
   ```

   instead of the intended

   ```
   /home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food/Filename.mp3
                                          ^           ^
   ```

   A neat way of fixing this would be to assign the path to a variable instead of including it in your program twice, then use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to combine the path components, e.g:

   ```
   path = "/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food"
   randomfile = os.path.join(path, random.choice(os.listdir(path)))
   ```
3. You are not including a space between the command `mixer` and the filename. Add one:

   ```
   os.system("mixer " + randomfile)
                  ^^^
   ```

Comment: Added the changes to the file now I only get sh: 1: mixer: not found 
```python                                                                                                
from pygame import mixer


def rndfoodpkr ():
    path = "/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food"
    randomfile = os.path.join(path, random.choice(os.listdir(path)))
    file = '/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food/' + randomfile
    os.system ("mixer " + file)```                                                                                     I apologise, new to python and using stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Why are you suffixing the file name with a `/` character? That's *possibly* telling whatever application you're passing it to that it's a directory (so it could, for example, play every file in that directory - no necessarily the case but it certainly wouldn't be totally bizarre behavior).

See for example, the following transcript:

```
>> touch wendy.mp3
>> aplay wendy.mp3/ # Note the / at the end.
wendy.mp3/: Not a directory
```

In any case, I suspect the problem may be the *missing* `/` between the path and the file name, and the missing space between the command and the argument. That's likely to give you a full command of:

```
mixer/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/FoodWendys.mp4
```

So the *first* think I would try would be to move the `/` to where it belongs and put the space in, something like:

```
cmd = 'mixer /home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker/Food/{}'.format(randomfile)
cmd = 'mixer {}'.format(os.path.join('/home/pi/share/Programs/FoodPicker', randomfile))
```

The latter (with `os.path.join`) is considered more portable.

If your code still doesn't work after making those changes (or you want to debug), just *print out* the command before using it:

```
print("Command is '{}'".format(cmd))
```

A great *many* problems can be solved just by looking at what the computer is seeing<sup>(1)</sup>.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> This also works for wives, apparently :-)